# remove string from coredata swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i am trying to remove one string from coredata and i created this func:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
        self.statusArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        // Rimuovo da CoreData
        var appDel = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        var context : NSManagedObjectContext! = appDel.managedObjectContext!

        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Status")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

        let result:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!
        context.deleteObject(result[indexPath.row] as! Status)

        context.save(nil)

    }
}
```

but actually this one give me the SIGABRT error when i try to delete something from the tableView! What is wrong with this function?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following example for deleting.It might be helpful.

```
var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Status")
var new_sync_details =  NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Status", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! NSManagedObject
var err: NSErrorPointer?


if var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil) as? [Status] {
                println("\nResults count: \(results.count)")
                for param in results{
                    println("\nResults param: \(param)")
                    new_sync_details.managedObjectContext!.deleteObject(param as NSManagedObject)
                }
}
```